# Find surface area of $z= x^2 - y^2$ inside cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the surface area of the "pringle" formed by the part of the surface 
*$$z = x^2 - y^2$$* lying inside the cylinder $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ I think the formula for the Surface Area is $$\int \int \sqrt{(3x^2)^2 + (-2y)^2 +1} \,rdrd\theta$$ but I am not too sure. Likewise, I'm not too sure what my bounds are since it is hard for me to visualize the surface to which I am integrating. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The surface integral is over a unit disk

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \sqrt{(2x)^2 + (-2y)^2 +1} \,rdrd\theta$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^1 \sqrt{4r^2+1}rdr=\frac\pi6(5\sqrt5-1)$$

Comment: Hi Quanto, thank you for your solution. How did you know the surface integral was over a unit disk? Also, why were the partials equal to 2x and -2y respectively? I thought the partials of z were $3x^2$ and -2y (respectively).

Comment: @asuhdude - the surface area lies inside the cylinder, which has a unit disk cross-section as the integral region. The partial derivative of $z=x^2-y^2$ is $z_x’= 2x$ and $z_y’=-2y$.